# Set form element parameters via FormBuilder

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I'm building a reactive form. The template looks like this...

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)="procesForm()" novalidate>
   <input type="text" formControlName="myInput" required>
   <button>Create Group</button>
</form>
```

...and I'm using `FormBuilder` to put it together like this...

```
newGroupForm:FormGroup;

private createForm(){
   this.newGroupForm = this.fb.group({
      newGroupName: [{value: '', disabled: false}]
   });
}
```

This works fine to set the two params `value` and `disabled` but if I try and set any others such as `required`, `placeholder`, `id` etc...

```
private createForm(){
   this.newGroupForm = this.fb.group({
      newGroupName: [{value: '', disabled: false, placeholder:'Enter value'}]
   });
}
```

...then when the page renders the displayed value of my input element is `[object Object]`.

So, is it possible to set other parameters of form elements through `FormBuilder` this way? I'm particularly interested in any way to set the elements `placeholder` value.

Comment: No it's not possible to set placeholder value like that :)

Comment: Short, sweet, to the point. Good answer :)

Comment: pass the placehoder text into value, and filter it when you receive. not straight forward ;)

Comment: @popClingwrap Gotta look out for not wearing out my keyboard :P :P